# How do I unmarshal a PyCodeObject using PyO3?

Tags: python, rust, unmarshalling, ffi, pyo3

I am reading .pyc files, and need to be able to unmarshal code objects. When I try to downcast the unmarshalled `PyAny` to `PyCodeObject`, I get the following error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `pyo3::ffi::code::PyCodeObject: pyo3::type_object::PyTypeInfo` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:179:47
    |
179 |         let code = *(loads(py, &code_buffer)?.downcast::<PyCodeObject>()?);
    |                                               ^^^^^^^^ the trait `pyo3::type_object::PyTypeInfo` is not implemented for `pyo3::ffi::code::PyCodeObject`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `for<'py> pyo3::conversion::PyTryFrom<'py>` for `pyo3::ffi::code::PyCodeObject`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `pyo3::ffi::code::PyCodeObject: pyo3::instance::PyNativeType` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:179:47
    |
179 |         let code = *(loads(py, &code_buffer)?.downcast::<PyCodeObject>()?);
    |                                               ^^^^^^^^ the trait `pyo3::instance::PyNativeType` is not implemented for `pyo3::ffi::code::PyCodeObject`
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `for<'py> pyo3::conversion::PyTryFrom<'py>` for `pyo3::ffi::code::PyCodeObject`
```

What is the proper way to do this?

#### MCVE

```rs
use pyo3::{ffi::PyCodeObject, marshal::loads, Python};

fn main() {
    let gil_guard = Python::acquire_gil();
    let py = gil_guard.python();
    let code_buffer = &include_bytes!("__pycache__/test.cpython-37.pyc")[16..];
    let code = *(loads(py, &code_buffer)
        .unwrap()
        .downcast::<PyCodeObject>()
        .unwrap());
}
```

### To create the test file:

1. Create a .py file
2. Import the module in Python (e.g. `python(3) -c 'import ...'`)
3. There should be a .pyc file in the `__pycache__` folder
4. Replace the path in the code in the call to `include_bytes!` with the actual path

---

## Version info

- Rust 2018
- rustc 1.43.0-nightly (564758c4c 2020-03-08)
- cargo 1.43.0-nightly (bda50510d 2020-03-02)
- CPython 3.7.3
- PyO3 0.9.1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210200/discussion-on-question-by-solomon-ucko-how-do-i-unmarshal-a-pycodeobject-using-p).

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured out how to do this:

```rs
let code_ptr = loads(py, &code_buffer)?.as_ptr() as *mut PyCodeObject;
// This should be valid, since PyCodeObject is Copy, as long as the refcount is positive
let code = unsafe { *code_ptr };
```

Comment: @user4815162342 Neither `extract` nor `as_ref` are valid. I think the issue is that [PyCodeObject](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.9.1/pyo3/ffi/struct.PyCodeObject.html) doesn't implement any of the necessary traits...